# How nested lazy loading can be achieve in angular 4.3.1?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, router, nested-routes, router-outlet

App is working fine but the Upload child routes are accessible without '/upload' too. For example '/photo', '/advertisement'. This should not be happen. I don't know why this is happening. If anyone know the solution then please reply.

app.routing.ts

```
{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: '', loadChildren: 'app/campsite/campsite.module#CampsiteModule'},
{path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/login/login.module#LoginModule'}
```

campsite.routing.ts

```
path: '', component: CampsiteComponent, children: [
{path: 'dashboard', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'gallery', component: GalleryComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'upload', loadChildren: './upload/upload.module#UploadModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
]
```

upload.routing.ts

```
path: '', component: UploadComponent, children: [
{path: 'photo', component: PhotoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'advertisement', component: AdvertisementComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'video', component: VideoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{path: 'logo', component: LogoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{ path: 'photo', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'photo' }
]
```

[Lazy Component Upload is loading in App Component Routing too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJj2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug: https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router/issues/45. :(

I have the same issue. I think a good path forward - which is not the best, as you will see - is not lazy loading the nested module until this is corrected:

1. Import `UploadModule` into `CampsiteModule`
2. Declare all your routes in `CampsiteModule`

...which is very, very ugly and harder to maintain.

There's a note in that link above concerning translations, but I didn't try it. (It also seems like an odd hack.)

For reference, if you look at how webpack generates your modules (from `ng serve` and such), you'll probably see only `campsite.module.chunk.js`, not `campsite.module.chunk.js` alongside `upload.module.chunk.js`.

Good luck!

Comment: Try Angular 4.3.6 before anything else, though. :)

Comment: If I follow the above two steps, then it can't be lazy load anymore. It happens same in angular 4.3.6

Comment: I see - you're lazy loading the module twice. :) (I needed more coffee, and I switched to decaf, which is clearly not working.)

Comment: I did a test of `A` --> `C` and `A` --> `B` --> `C`, and the routes all work (no hard loading; all when the application is in a "warm" state). What's in your `AuthGuard`? Do you have a CoreModule, off hand? I can create a plunker, if I find the time. (Probably sometime tomorrow.)

Comment: Auth Guard

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
        if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
        return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    }

Comment: Twice where I lazy loading it?